# Apache Hive- Understanding partitioning in hive

Tags: hive

i am trying to learn apache hive and was going through Oreilly Programming Hive and had some problem understanding partitioning in hive. The following is the query:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
 name STRING,
 salary FLOAT,
 subordinates ARRAY<STRING>,
 deductions MAP<STRING, FLOAT>,
 address STRUCT<street:STRING, city:STRING, state:STRING, zip:INT>
)
PARTITIONED BY (country STRING, state STRING);
```

Here i am creating a partition depending on the country and state. But, there is no such field as country in the table's metadata and how does partition work in this case? How does hive manages to do this work?

Also can anyone please share some datasets to work on..

How is the data loaded into this kind of table?

Comment: There *is* such a field in **metadata**, but not inside the **data** files. Because the partitiniong key(s) are used to create *sub-directories*, so when you access a data file, the value of the partitioning key(s) is/are *implicit*. But they are displayed in a SELECT query, after the "regular" columns.

Comment: RTFM: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-DynamicPartitionInserts and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-Dynamic-PartitionInsert

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITIONED BY` doesn't mean that your are going to split the data based on these existing columns, but that you are going to **add** these "columns" as a way of organizing your table (or more precisely, the file structure to store the data).

The partition keys will affect the data storage structure in Hive. In this case, Hive will create two "subfolders" under "employees" ("country" and "state") and will use these partition keys as regular columns, which you can use in your (more efficient) `SELECT`queries (`WHERE country = something AND state = other`), as well as in your [data loadings](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML).
By means of specifying these keys in your loads and selects, Hive will be able to store and retrieve the data faster, since the data storage is now organized.

[Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions) has plenty of datasets (and of many diferentes topics) that you can use. They are mainly aimed at the use of Machine Learning algorithms, but nothing prevents you from using them to your own training.